# Candy for MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, haml

I'm currently experimenting with Sinatra and MongoDB (through the Candy gem). I love the Candy coding style, but I'm having a few issues when I try to retrieve all of the *Post* objects. Here's my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'candy'
require 'haml'

Candy.db = "Miroir"

class Post
    include Candy::Piece
end

class Posts
    include Candy::Collection
    collects :post
end

get '/' do
    @posts = Posts.all
    haml :index
end
```

When it renders *index.haml*, all I get is *Post (4d0ac53d9b6d4202a3000001){}*, and I can't retrieve any of the data. The haml is:

```
!!! 5
%html
    %body
        %strong Posts
        %ul
        - @posts.each do |post|
            %li= post
```

How can I iterate the titles of the posts in the ul? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Candy that requires you refresh the object before it'll populate the data when you do a find using a collection.

Do it like so:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
        post.refresh
        %li= post
```